cisco anyconnect vpn client on ubuntu server 22.04
Good day all,
I am trying to do some research on whether it is possible to install and use cisco anyconnect on ubuntu server 22.04 with only a terminal.
Every tutorial I have seen, even the official Cisco one shows it being done through a GUI on the desktop.
I was going to try and download anyconnect to see if I could poke around a config file but sadly there is no trial version.
Please let me know if anyone has been able to do this. We need to get our IT security stamp of approval for this, and to do so they said that the client must be anyconnect.
Thank you very much

A good question to ask Cisco as it is their software.
